# How to achieve post_status__not_in?

Tags: pre-get-posts

How to fetch all posts with any status except trash and draft

```
function pre_filter( $query ){

     if ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == $this->post_type ) {

       if ( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] )  ) {

          $query->set('post_status__not_in', array( 'trash', 'draft' ) );
       }

     }

}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code before posting, make it more readable :-) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `post_status__not_in` query argument, but you can simply query for all statuses *other than* trash & draft:

```
$stati = array_keys( get_post_stati() );
unset( $stati['trash'], $stati['draft'] );
$stati = array_flip( $stati );

$query->set( 'post_status', $stati );
```